# Error when imputing minimum values using SimpleImputer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data, imputation

I'm trying to use the minimum values of each column to replace missing values but keep getting an error. Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
numeric_cols = [X_test.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns]
numeric_df = X_test.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
for col in numeric_cols:
    my_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=X_test[col].min())
    imputed_numeric_X_test = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(numeric_df))
    imputed_numeric_X_test.columns = numeric_df.columns
```

This is the error I get when I run it:

```
ValueError: 'fill_value'=MSSubClass         20.0
LotFrontage        21.0
LotArea          1470.0
OverallQual         1.0
OverallCond         1.0
YearBuilt        1879.0
YearRemodAdd     1950.0
MasVnrArea          0.0
BsmtFinSF1          0.0
BsmtFinSF2          0.0
BsmtUnfSF           0.0
TotalBsmtSF         0.0
1stFlrSF          407.0
2ndFlrSF            0.0
LowQualFinSF        0.0
GrLivArea         407.0
BsmtFullBath        0.0
BsmtHalfBath        0.0
FullBath            0.0
HalfBath            0.0
BedroomAbvGr        0.0
KitchenAbvGr        0.0
TotRmsAbvGrd        3.0
Fireplaces          0.0
GarageYrBlt      1895.0
GarageCars          0.0
GarageArea          0.0
WoodDeckSF          0.0
OpenPorchSF         0.0
EnclosedPorch       0.0
3SsnPorch           0.0
ScreenPorch         0.0
PoolArea            0.0
MiscVal             0.0
MoSold              1.0
YrSold           2006.0
dtype: float64 is invalid. Expected a numerical value when imputing numerical data
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleImputer` only supports a single value for `fill_value`, not a per-column specification.  Adding that was discussed in [Issue19783](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19783), but passed on, and wouldn't support taking the columnwise minimum anyway.  I can't find any discussion to add a custom callable option for `strategy`, which would seem to be the clearest solution.  So I think you're stuck doing it manually or with a custom transformer.  To do it somewhat manually, you could use the `ColumnTransformer` approach specified in the linked Issue.